# How to order an array property by any of its properties in Redisgraph?

Tags: cypher, redisgraph

I'm using Redisgraph. I have two node types, *Driver* and *Race*, with a relationship from Driver to Race called *racedAt*. I know that if I query:

```
MATCH (r:Race)<-[p:racedAt]-(d:Driver)
RETURN r,p
```

This returns me the same race n times, where n is the number of drivers. To solve this, I use:

```
MATCH (r:Race)<-[p:racedAt]-(d:Driver)
RETURN r, collect(p) as p
```

to have a single *Race* in *_values[0]* and every *racedAt* in *_values[1]*.

Lets' suppose that the racedAt relationship has a property, *position*; what can I do to sort the _values[1] array by its inner property position?

The result I have:

```
_values[0]: { name: 'Monza' }
_values[1]: [ { driver: 'Hamilton', position: '2'}, { driver: 'Verstappen', position: '1'} ]
```

The result I want:

```
_values[0]: { name: 'Monza' }
_values[1]: [ { driver: 'Verstappen', position: '1'}, { driver: 'Hamilton', position: '2'} ]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ORDER BY` before you collect the results:

```sql
MATCH (r:Race)<-[p:racedAt]-(d:Driver)
WITH r, p
ORDER BY p.position
RETURN r, collect(p) AS p
```

Comment: Thank you @Brakebein!